# How to use same panel from different html files in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use a panel defined, in index.html in another page, e.g., resutls.html ?
Or do I need to define the panel in every page, and add the same html code in both pages ?

Since I want my panel to be same in all pages.

This is my panel in index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <!-- beginning of header -->
        <div data-role="navbar" data-id="navbar">
            <!-- beginning of presistant navbar, this navbar will be shown in all
            pages -->
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="index.html" data-icon="search" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Search</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="bars">More</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
```

Comment: you need to have panel in each page, you can use the same panel. You could clone it from page to another, or append fresh markup on `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: check this demo i made before, up to line #12 http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PRC8W/

Comment: @Omar It makes sense your code, thank you. How about the suggestion below using the same, panel and call it pragmatically with jQuery, does this work also ?

Comment: Appending code in variable is easier. However, before appending a panel into pages, you need to check whether there is a panel previously inserted or not by `$.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-panel').length` if length = 0, then append, else dont append.

Comment: @Omar ok thank you. But why not add this to answers, so I can choose it to be right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36535/discussion-between-omar-and-lali-pali)

Answer (score 1):

If the two pages are on the same domain name you could simply load that element into your new page using JQuery.

However this is not very SEO friendly as your links are being dynamically loaded into the page.

You will need to include the JQuery library then make the div on your new page, lets say:

`<div class="new-sidebar"></div>`

Then load its contents with JQuery `$('.new-sidebar').load('index.html #mypanel');`

## Edit from comment:

```
$( "#navbar ul li" ).click(function() {
  $('.new-sidebar').load('index.html #mypanel');
});
```

Comment: What If I need to open the panel, from a link and not jQuery code ? I have a persistent navbar I want to use to open the panel.

Comment: Then you could assign an onclick event with JQuery, where if your navbar is clicked it will do that function.

Comment: See the click event I have added to my answer. When you click on an `<li>` it will then load #mypanel from index.html into the div .new-sidebar on the current page.

Comment: What click you code listens, to, is it a button or any click, since you don't have any other condition in the click function ?

Comment: The click function is when you click an `<li>` inside a `<ul>` inside an element with the id of `"navbar"`